# Discrete Math Induction Proof for summation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, proof-explanation

I am trying to follow the steps of an induction proof but I do not understand how they got to the final answer.

At part (4), how did they get that inequality? What happened to the '2' in the inductive step inequality just above it? I am unsure how they went from the inductive step to part (4)

[image: Induction Proof]

Comment: This proof is by ordinary induction, not strong induction.

Comment: You are right, my bad @GerryMyerson

Answer (score 1):

Based on the inductive hypothesis, you need to show that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac1{i^2}\le2-\frac1{k+1}\ .$$
You have already shown (second last line) that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac1{i^2}\le2-\frac1k+\frac1{(k+1)^2}\ .$$
So you now wish to prove
$$2-\frac1k+\frac1{(k+1)^2}\le2-\frac1{k+1}\ ,$$
that is,
$$-\frac1k+\frac1{(k+1)^2}\le-\frac1{k+1}\ .$$
The book leaves you to do this as an exercise.

Comment: In the second last line why is it ≤ (less than or equal) and why don't they just use = (equal) for the summation of i=1 to (k+1)

Comment: Because the aim is to prove something$\le$something else.  There is no need to prove they are equal.  Suppose you want to prove $x\le3$ and you know how to prove $x\le2$.  Does this mean for sure that $x\le3$?  Does it matter that $2\ne3$?

Comment: Note that the next step, after simplification, is to show that $(k+1)^2 \ge k(k+1)$.